# Find text using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have some html like such that I need to somehow select out using dojo:

```
<tr>
<td class="form-label-text">Thumbnail Small:</td>
<td></td>
<td class="form-inset">
<span class="disabledText">Not Available</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

The only unique thing about this than other rows is the "Thumbnail Small:" part.

I know jquery has a :contiains selector http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

I cannot find an equivalent way to do this using Dojo.

(Modification to the original html is not an option)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I dont think we have similar thing in Dojo library , but you can go for custom Dojo implementation.

```
dojo.query("td").filter(function(node){
if(dojo.attr(node,"innerHTML")==="Thumbnail Small:")
    return node;
})[0];
```

I have prepared a JSFiddle here for you : http://jsfiddle.net/t6u05ket/

Comment: This similar to what I resorted to but much nicer.

Does dojo allow me to simply define my own function which does this? like 
dojo.query("td").myFilter("Thumbnail Small:")

Comment: dojo.query returns a Nodelist. For this kind of feature you would need to add feature to Nodelist. I think prototype inheritance would be helpful here. Something like : NodeList.prototype.myFilter=function(){..}